# recover matlab command history

Tags: matlab, backup

Accidentally I deleted my Matlab command history, is there a way to recover it?
Matlab autosaves the history at history.m in the prefdir, so now the history.m file is totally empty, is there a backup file somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. If you clear the command history from inside Matlab, there's no recovery. Matlab clears the history and saves an empty xml in place of the old one. If you deleted it outside Matlab, have you checked the recycle bin?

Comment: Check if  you had diary mode on `get(0,'Diary')`

Comment: I think there's nothing you can do right now. But you can prevent the problem from happening again, by making regular backups yourself. One possibility is to put some code in your `startup.m` that makes a zip-file of your whole prefdir.